# How to fix strange artifacts when applying Gaussian blur in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, framebuffer, gaussianblur

I am getting strange artifacts when applying Gaussian Blur for a bloom effect in OpenGL ES 2.0 (with QT), as you can see below.  On the left is with the bloom effect enabled, and on the right is with the effect turned off:

[image]

Strangely, this artifacting is only happening when I render certain lines, as you can see from the picture below.  For what it's worth, these lines are actually quads that are being rendered to the screen with a constant pixel width.  No other objects have any visible artifacting, just the expected Gaussian Blur, and even more strangly, most other lines that I've been rendering look just fine.  You can see in the left picture that the cyan line on the left gets rendered without any weird artifacting.

Here are the shaders I've put together:

Vertex Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 aPos;
attribute vec2 aTexCoords;

varying vec2 blurTextureCoords[11];
varying vec2 texCoords;

uniform vec2 screenRes; // image width
uniform int effectType;

void main(void){

    // Set GL position
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
    texCoords = aTexCoords;


    if(effectType == 2){
        // Horizontal blur
        vec2 centerTexCoords = vec2(aPos.x, aPos.y)*0.5 + 0.5; // Coordinates of center of texture
        float pixelSize = 1.0 / screenRes.x;

        // Fill out texture coord array
        for(int i=-5; i<=5; i++){
            float i_float = float(i);
            blurTextureCoords[i+5] = centerTexCoords + vec2(pixelSize * i_float, 0.0);
        }
    }
    else if(effectType == 3){
        // Vertical blur
        vec2 centerTexCoords = vec2(aPos.x, aPos.y)*0.5 + 0.5; // Coordinates of center of texture
        float pixelSize = 1.0 / screenRes.y;

        // Fill out texture coord array
        for(int i=-5; i<=5; i++){
            float i_float = float(i);
            blurTextureCoords[i+5] = centerTexCoords + vec2(0.0, pixelSize * i_float);
        }
    }
}
```

Frag shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 blurTextureCoords[11];
varying vec2 texCoords;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;
uniform sampler2D sceneTexture;
uniform int effectType;

void main(void){
    vec4 color = texture2D(screenTexture, texCoords);

    // Different effects
    if(effectType == 2 || effectType == 3){
        // Blur
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[0]) * 0.0093;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[1]) * 0.028002;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[2]) * 0.065984;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[3]) * 0.121703;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[4]) * 0.175713;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[5]) * 0.198596;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[6]) * 0.175713;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[7]) * 0.121703;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[8]) * 0.065984;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[9]) * 0.028002;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(screenTexture, blurTextureCoords[10]) * 0.0093;
    }
    else{
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
```

I've been unable to find anything strange in other parts of my code, and it's really weird that only these specific lines are messed up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this!  I needed to clamp the color values of my sampled texture coordinates between 0 and 1, since I'm using HDR and these values are saturating the Gaussian Blur effect.